# set Tag to Every Child in expandable list

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I using Expandable list in my project.I extends BaseExpandableListAdapter,I want to set unique tag to every child, i use following code to set tag:

```
     public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ArrayList<String> childtemp= (ArrayList<String>) childitems.get(groupPosition);


    final ViewHolder holder;
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = inflatter.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
        holder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.childrow);
        holder.checked = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.childcheck);
        v.setTag(holder);

        holder.checked.setChecked(false);
        holder.checked.setTag(groupPosition*100+childPosition);
        holder.text.setTag(groupPosition*100+childPosition);
     }
     else {
        ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).text.setTag(groupPosition*100+childPosition);
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        getid = (Integer) holder.text.getTag();
        check(getid , holder);  
        }

     holder.text.setText(childtemp.get(childPosition).toString());
```

and its working for first position that i expand but when I expand another position tag not set because convertView is not null. how can doing something that for every child set tag?? i override onGroupExpanded but i dont know how use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    List<String> childtemp= (List<String>) childitems.get(groupPosition);

    final ViewHolder holder;
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = inflatter.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
        holder.text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.childrow);
        holder.checked = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.childcheck);
        v.setTag(holder);

        holder.checked.setChecked(false);
     }
     else {
        ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).text.setTag(groupPosition*100+childPosition);
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        getid = (Integer) holder.text.getTag();
        check(getid , holder);  
     }

     holder.checked.setTag(groupPosition*100+childPosition);
     holder.text.setTag(groupPosition*100+childPosition);
     holder.text.setText(childtemp.get(childPosition).toString());
```

Comment: sir @Autocrab,.....i am getting an error like "The key must be an application-specific resource id" while setting the tag